# Spatial Join does not return no point inside geometry Python

Tags: polygon, geopandas, spatial-join, shapely, rasterio

I have a geodataframe containing 200 000 entries with Points, and I want to check which coordinates are inside a geodataframe containing 20 000 polygons that I am creating. The polygons are created from a masked raster, under certain conditions that I define. The problem appears when making a spatial join between both dataframes (checking the points inside the polygons) returns that no point is inside the polygons. I have an external app where I can visualize the points, and we are sure that the points must be inside the polygons.

I attach the code that I'm using:

```
#Polygonize the raster: 
mask = None
with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open(class_raster_path) as src:
        image = src.read(1) # first band
        results = (
        {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': s}
        for i, (s, v) 
        in enumerate(
            shapes(image, mask=mask, transform=src.transform)))

geoms = list(results)
polygonized_raster  = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms)

#Delete the polygons created from 0 values (we don't want those regions of the raster)
polygonized_raster = polygonized_raster.loc[polygonized_raster.raster_val != 0.]

#Load the Points gdf:
snow_file_gdf = gpd.read_file(snow_depth_path, crs= 'EPSG:4326')

#Check points inside the polygons: 
PiP_gdf = gpd.sjoin(snow_file_gdf, polygonized_raster, how='inner', predicate='within')
```

I also tried the gpd.within and gpd.intersects (adapting the code when needed) but nothing is working to obtain the points that are inside the polygons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to declare the crs during geopandas object initialization, so you need to modify your code like this :

```py
geoms = list(results)
polygonized_raster  = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms, crs=4326)

polygonized_raster = polygonized_raster.loc[polygonized_raster.raster_val != 0.]

# Here crs is only required if your 'snow_depth_path' crs is undeclared
snow_file_gdf = gpd.read_file(snow_depth_path, crs=4326)

PiP_gdf = gpd.sjoin(snow_file_gdf, polygonized_raster, how='inner', predicate='within')
```

If you need to set the crs after creating your gdf, you may also use the `GeoDataFrame.set_crs` function.

If this is still not working, it may be due to errors in the first part (polygonization).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've properly implemented the CRS, but it is not working either. 
I dont't know where it's the problem, because I opened with QGiS the polygons and they are ok.

Comment: You need to check if your source raster also have a projection. If not, coordinates will be in pixel units, sore completely out of bounds. You can use the `gdalinfo` command to check that.   

Edit : which polygons did you check with qgis, the vectorized ones ? Have you checked with a basemap like OSM, to see if they are indeed localized at the right location ?

Comment: You can also use rasterio to check your input image, i.e.
`print(src.profile['crs'], src.profile['transform'])`